# I get the wrong output from .txt file in C - Linux

Tags: c, linux, file

I have 2d char array. I storing history of 20 commands passed to my own shell. But i have a trouble on it. When i compile it on Windows with CodeBlocks everything goes fine

MAXHIS = 20
commandTable is [20][100]:

```
    void addHistory(char *command) //add command to 2d table
    {
    int i;
    char *tempCommand = command;
    if(tempHis < MAXHIS)
    {
        strcpy(commandTable[tempHis], tempCommand);
        tempHis++;
    }
    else
        for(i = 0; i < MAXHIS; i++)
        {
            if(i<MAXHIS-1)
            {
                strcpy(commandTable[i], commandTable[i+1]);
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(commandTable[i], tempCommand);
            }
        }

}

void loadHistory() //load history from file
{
    FILE *file= fopen(filename, "r");
    int fileEnd = 0;
    int i, j;
    char c;
    while(1)
    {
        if((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
        {

            if(c == '\n')
            {
                i++;
                j = 0;
                tempHis++;
            }

            commandTable[i][j] = c;
            j++;

        }
        else
        {
            fileEnd = 1;
        }
        if (fileEnd == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void printHistory(void) //display history on the shell
{
    int i;
    printf("\n");
    for(i = 0; i < tempHis; i++)
        printf("Command %d: %s \n",i+1, commandTable[i]);
}

void writeHistory(FILE *file) //write history to the file
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < tempHis; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%c", commandTable[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(file, "\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

and int Main:

```
int main(void) {
    setFilepath();
    FILE *historyFile= fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (signal(SIGQUIT, sigHandler) == SIG_ERR)
    printf("SIGQUIT ERROR");
    loadHistory();
    //some code here
    return 0;
}
```

And commands for manipulate my history features:

```
int lineInMenu(char* line, char** argsList, FILE *file)
{
    if(strcmp(line, "exit")==0)
    {
        writeHistory(file);
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(strcmp(line, "history") ==0)
    {
        printHistory();
        return 1;
    }
    else if(strcmp(argsList[0],"cd")==0)
    {
        chdir(argsList[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Before i first time close the shell everything is fine (with "print History") and it looks like this:

```
Command 1: ls
Command 2: ls
Command 3: history
```

When i compile shell again (loadHistory() from file) i get some empty blanks, it looks like:

```
Command 1: ls
Command 2:

Command 3:
ls

Command 4:
history

Command 5 : history
```

And when i try again, i get more of empty space. Can someone check my code to tells me, what im doing wrong?

if it will help, .txt file looks like (when i first time close shell):

```
ls\00\00\00\.....
\00\00\00\00...
\00\00\00\00..
history\00\00\..
\00\00\00\..
\00\00\00..
```

Best whishes

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're not handling the `\n` correctly? If you get one you add it to the start of the next line.

Comment: I think it is the way. loadHistory() its looks like my function cant handle '/n' properly.

Comment: but how to repair that thing? After closing shell i always get wrong output from file with empty "Command: " blanks, and commands are moved to new line (not straight "Command: 1 'command' but smth like Command: 1 '\ncommand'

Comment: Hardly a difficult problem to solve - just don't do `commandTable[i][j] = c;` if `c` is a `\n`. Or if it's a `\r` too.

Comment: Where is tempHis declared?

Comment: tempHis is a global variable, i declare it on start of program by 

int tempHis = 0;

Comment: in the function: `loadHistory()`, the variables: `i` and `j` are not initialized! They should both be initialized to 0.  Also, `i` and `j` are meaningless names.  suggest using: `row` and `column`

Comment: the function: `fgetc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`  This is especially important when comparing with `EOF` which is an `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved few days ago. I just added "Continue" in "LoadHistory" method (where if(c == \n) in the end of thsi if)

Answer (score 0):

the function: loadHistory()

1. contains some logic errors like where to place the '\n'
2. fails to check the status of the call to `fopen()`
3. uses meaningless variable names
4. fails to initialize the variables
5. fails to let the caller to this function know if the function was successful or not
6. fails to properly make use of the returned status from `fgetc()`
7. makes an invalid comparison between a `int` and `char`
8. is missing some needed parens

Caveat:  I have not checked the other functions:

The following proposed code:
corrects the obvious problems with the function:

Suggest using something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // fopen(), fgetc(), FILE, EOF
#include <string.h>   // memset()
#include <stdlib.h>   // EXIT_FAILURE  EXIT_SUCCESS

#define MAX_ROWS 20
#define MAX_COLS 80

// prototypes
int loadHistory( char * );

extern int tempHis;
extern char commandTable[ MAX_ROWS ][ MAX_COLS ];


int loadHistory( char *filename ) //load history from file
{
    FILE *file= fopen(filename, "r");
    if( !file )
    {
        perror( "fopen for history file failed" );
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int c;

    tempHis = 0;
    memset( &commandTable, '\0', sizeof( commandTable ) );

    while( (c = fgetc(file)) != EOF )
    {
        commandTable[ row ][ column ] = (char)c;
        column++;

        if( column >= MAX_COLS );
        {
            fclose( file );
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        if(c == '\n')
        {
            row++;
            if( row >= MAX_ROWS )
            {
                fclose( file );
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            column = 0;
            tempHis++;
        }
    }

    fclose( file );
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```